# Lining up data with Titanium

Tags: javascript, format, titanium

I need to display 5 lines of summary data at the bottom of a listview. I created a footer and tried:

```
label1.text+num.toString()
footer.add(label1) // repeat for 5 labels
listview.add(footer)
```

where the five labels were fixed length strings, but no go, still not lining up properly. I've read some posts about tableviews, is this what I need?

Edit: monospace fonts work, but still...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your first statement:

```
label1.text+num.toString()
```

I think it should be:

```
label1.text = num.toString();
```

That can explain that you didn't see any label.

If it isn't the solution and the labels have the text property set to anything before your statements, please provide more code in order to help you.

Comment: My bad, the typo is here only. Unfortunately, I don't think it's a code issue. Strings with proportional fonts just don't line up.

Comment: I fixed it.  I used a createview as a container and put my summary line labels in with left,etc set. Thanks for helping. Should I post (brief) code showing what I did?

Comment: Yes, you can post answers to your own questions if you figured it out by yourself. It could be helpful for somebody else with similar problem looking through archived questions.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my issue with lining items up properly was to create a view then .add individual elements to it with top/left positioning.

```
var summary_win2 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    height: '50%',
    top: 0
});


 // summary_win2.add(summary_win2_label0);
 // I did the above code for all the elements below

var summary_win2_label0 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Data 1",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 0,
    left:3 
});

var summary_win2_data0 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "0",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 0,
    left:120 
});

var summary_win2_label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Data 2",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 25,
    left:3 
});

var summary_win2_data1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "0",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 25,
    left:120 
});


var summary_win2_label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Data 3",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 50,
    left:3
});

var summary_win2_data2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "0",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 50,
    left:120 
});


var summary_win2_label3 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Data 4",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 75,
    left:3
});

var summary_win2_data3 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text: "0",
    font:{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'normal'},
    color:'#000',
    top: 75,
    left:120
});

var buttonClear_win2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Clear',
     top: 110, 
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    left: 0
});
```